# Apps ask for NAS credentials on startup

Tags: nas

On system security councilor's advice on my Synology NAS, I have disabled the admin account and replaced it by a different account with admin privileges.

Since that time, various apps on MacOS ask for the password of the admin account on my NAS, e.g. the MacOS Microsoft Teams client. They keep asking for the credentials even after I have entered the new ones and stored them in the key chain. Teams for example ask as often as three times in a row before rendering the UI. And it doesn't really matter what I enter. If I cancel the dialog, Teams will still start properly. Even when shutting down Teams, it again asks for the credentials - only once, though.

I've tried to rename com.microsoft.teams.plist and com.microsoft.teams.helper.plist in my ~/Library/Preferences folder. No luck.

I've also tried to rename the folder ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Teams. No luck.

NAS supports SMB-3 perfectly well. I have the share open in Finder, anyway.

There are other apps with the same issue. OwnCloud, for one.

Any other ideas?

EDIT: Some global most recently used list with references to the old account, maybe?

Comment: I think I'd want to know why Teams wants to access the NAS at all, vs figuring out how to correct the password,

Comment: It is not only the Teams client, so Microsoft bashing is not the solution (here). OwnCloud, 1Password and some other apps have the same issue. Seems to be some global config. We normally do not notice because if the credentials are correct, no dialog will ever show up.

Comment: RE: "so Microsoft bashing is not the solution (here). " -- Who's Microsoft bashing? Was there another comment, now deleted, that bashed Microsoft?

Comment: Just kidding. Didn't mean to offend anyone...

Comment: Just followed the idea of a global MRU list. I removed the folder com.apple.sharedfilelist from ~/Library/Application Support. No luck!

Comment: Just tried to deinstall / reinstall Teams including all appropriate files in Application Support. No Luck!

Comment: Did you try to delete all the entries in the keychain that contain info about the NAS?

Comment: I would have answered: "Sure, how dare you...." But I double checked. What I have done is adding additional items to the keychain. I didn't remove the old ones. Now I did. And things changed: Teams now informs me that it wants to connect to the NAS and asks for credentials after I have accepted the connection. Now, after giving the new credentials and saving them to the keychain, it stopped nagging.
Your tip did the trick.

Comment: I still wonder why Teams insists to connect to the NAS three times on startup. But that's actually a different questions in the end. And there is one more question: When asking for the credentials, the user "admin" was pre-filled even though I have removed all entries from the keychain. Where does this user name come from. It still seems to be some sort of configuration somewhere in the system.

Comment: Are you mounting the NAS shares in your Startup Items within your user account? Did you setup Time Machine on the NAS? Do anything with trying to auto mount via files in /etc?